# Why isn't the Stackexchange logo posted on the ASP.NET Get Started Page?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, logo

On the [ASP.NET Get Started](http://www.asp.net/get-started) Page **(See the logo in the Customer Section)**, we can see that [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is one of ASP.NET main clients. They didn't include the  [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) logo instead which represents the entire range of Q&A products.

Rephrase Question:

1. Does Stack Exchange could possibly created using some other technology?

Comment: StackOverflow is a much more recognizable "brand" than the StackExchange one (for better or ill). If it were me, I'd pimp SO before SE.

Comment: May be I should rephrase my Question.... Shouldn't ask something silly...

Comment: Well, now the answer is just "no". That, or this could be closed as a dupe of [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

Comment: @lunboks: Thanks for that link. It show Stackoverflow technology, But not stackexchange. Could it possibly the same?

Comment: @Yeo Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites are using the same technology.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I think you have the final answer since you're more experience with it before. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Does Stackexchange could possibly created using some other technology?

No, the core Stack Exchange engine is the same throughout the network. Why Stack Overflow instead of Stack Exchange? Possible reasons:

- Stack Overflow was present prior to Stack Exchange came into existence
- Stack Overflow has a wider presence
- Stack Overflow is known & widely regarded amongst the programmer community

Comment: I'm pretty sure the third one was the biggest one. It's kind of hard to find a programmer that doesn't know what SO is these days, but Stack Exchange (as a brand) is not as well established. Case in point, a co-worker recently asked me "Hey, what's the URL to that Stack Overflow for parenting again?"

Comment: @TimPost yep - ran into the same situation yesterday - was wearing [webapps.se] t-shirt, he asked me about the site - told the person about Stack Exchange, he was clueless - had to mention Stack Overflow's parent company

Answer (score 1):

You're asking here why some other entity didn't include a logo? I don't think that's answerable... but let me have a shot at it:

1. Because they didn't feel like it. Maybe because `stackoverflow` has, because of its googleability, a wider group of people that recognize it? That would be the goal of that part probably.
2. No. That just means it wasn't included. Note that this answer does not mean that it IS created with ASP.net, it means that both things do not have anything to do with each other. (well, if it IS posted, then that's a high change it does use ASP.NET, so they do have... well, you know what i mean)

Comment: I agree, ASP.NET page target developers and I've read that 1/3 developer has already been once on SO. And the ones that are not SO members probably don't know it belong to the stackExchange network.

Comment: Sorry for my Silly Question... :-) I'm not meta person... But I'll try to be meta next time.. @alain.janinm Thanks, that makes more sense to me.. Sorry Can't upvote your comment